# Eclipse IDE : SGML plugin?

Tags: eclipse, sgml

Do you know a plugin for editing SGML files within Eclipse ?

Comment: If there is no eclipse plugin, you could still look for a standalone editor: see http://wiki.docbook.org/topic/DocBookAuthoringTools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now, there is no such plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) should do it. It has 2 versions. Standalone and Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Nothing on oXygen website suggests it allows SGML editing. Are you sure ?